# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token? :( special character

Tags: javascript

I have code of file html example

```html
<a onclick="alert('It&#39;s hot');">Click here</a>
```

I replace char `'` to `&#39;` . After I run this file.

Tab console of The browse show this error. When I check element in browser, it show

```
<a onclick="alert('It's hot');">Click here</a> // this is not correct
```

I want to show `It's hot` in alert box but I don't want to use `'It\'s hot'` or `"It's hot"` in my code.

It only is example to use `'` or `"` of text in JavaScript.

Is there another way?

Comment: *"but i dont want user 'It\'s hot' in my code or "It's hot""* ***Why not?*** Those are *how you do this*. You *can* use `&apos;` and `&quot;`, but that's fairly ugly.

Comment: “I want to show this but I don’t want to use these correct solutions that work”?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can use `&apos;` and `&quot;` instead of `'` and `"` respectively. These are unintuitive if you ask me, but they are perfectly usable. However, if you get a text which was created outside your control, then you will need to replace all apostrophes and quotes to achieve what you want, like this:

```
function getSomeText(input) {
    return input.split('"').join('&quote;').split("'").join('&apos;');
}
```